# Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

My motivation is to edit values displayed in this edit form. But when I press edit button it throws out this error. I can't figure it out. Can anyone help what is missing in my code?

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
>   mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route
>   "sokosimu_editor_edit_editoruser".") in
>   SokosimuEditorBundle:User:editUser.html.twig at line 7. 500 Internal
>   Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

**Router**

```
sokosimu_editor_edit_editoruser:
    path: /edit/editoruser/{user}
    defaults: {_controller:SokosimuEditorBundle:Editor:editEditorUser}
    requirements:
            _method:  GET|POST
```

**Controller**

```
    public function editEditorUserAction(User $user,Request $request){

    $form = $this->createForm(new EditUserType(),$user);

    //2. handle the submit (will happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form ->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()){
    }
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $editUser = $user ->getEditoruser();
    return $this->render('SokosimuEditorBundle:User:editUser.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
```

}

**View**

```
 {% block title %}Edit User{% endblock%}

 {% block body %}

<form action="{{ path('sokosimu_editor_edit_editoruser') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="formedit">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.alias)}}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {#{{ form_row(form.password) }}#}
    {{ form_row(form.mobile) }}
    {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
  </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

**Form**

```
<?php

 namespace Sokosimu\EditorBundle\Form\Type;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; 
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

 class EditUserType extends AbstractType
 {

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
     $builder->add('alias','text',array('required'=>false));
     $builder->add('email', 'email',array('required'=>true));
    // $builder->add('password','password',array('required'=>true));
     $builder->add('mobile','text',array('required'=>false));
     $builder->add('submit', 'submit');
  }

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface   $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Sokosimu\UserBundle\Entity\User'
     //   'data_class' => NULL
    ));
}

public function getName()
 {
   return 'editUser';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass user in the path:

```
<form action="{{ path('sokosimu_editor_edit_editoruser', {'user': user}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="formedit">
```

And in controller render the twig with user:

```
return $this->render('SokosimuEditorBundle:User:editUser.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'user' => $user
));
```

Comment: Thank you @panche14 you gave me idea for the answer I have commented below with some modification.

Answer (score 0):

Fix route to

```
sokosimu_editor_edit_editoruser:
    path: /edit/editoruser/{userId}
    defaults: {_controller:SokosimuEditorBundle:Editor:editEditorUser}
    requirements:
        _method:  GET|POST
```

Fix controller to

```
public function editEditorUserAction(Request $request, $userId)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SokosimuEditorBundle:User')->find($userId);
    $form = $this->createForm(new EditUserType(), $user);

    //2. handle the submit (will happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

        $editUser = $user->getEditoruser();
    }

    return $this->render('SokosimuEditorBundle:User:editUser.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help from @panche14, I have modified the code a bit.Answer from @panche14 returned object but the form @param expected to be string or integer.

`return $this->render('SokosimuEditorBundle:User:editUser.html.twig',
 array('form' => $form->createView(),
'user' => $user ->getId();
  ));`

Also add this in twig file:

> {'user': user}

as specified by @panche14

Now, the edit button works fine as desired.

Comment: You should have commented @panche14 answer so he could improve it instead of answering with almost the same content.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Its because I have to add code and answer could be ambiguous in comment.