# Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route in drupal 8

Tags: php, redirect, routes, drupal-8

Using drupal 8, in my account page I had a menu with view like custom_orders. In that page when I click to add new order, new form "*user/{user}/custom_orders/add*" will be opened. After submit that form page should be redirect to "*user/{user}/custom_orders*" this page.

I tried some,

```
custom_form:  
  path: '/user/{user}/custom-orders'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _access: 'TRUE'
    user: \d+
  options:
    no_cache: TRUE
```

And in form page, I have redirected like

```
$form_state->setRedirect('custom_form');
```

But it was not working.

I have already tried this,  [Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929936/some-mandatory-parameters-are-missing-user-to-generate-a-url-for-route)  but it was not working for me.